# Do two A's beat a wheel straight?

Tags: poker-strategy, reading-hands

Playing Hold'em poker and had a 10-J in hand, 9-Q-A on the table. Opponent held A-4 and won with a pair of A's. I thought I would win with the straight. Not so?

Comment: In all forms of poker I know - you need 5 cards for a straight and it looks like you're playing hold em so...no dice.

Comment: While more questions and hence more activity is desired on this site, there's no point having questions that can be answered with a 3-second Google search.

Comment: Clearly this needs more info to be answerable. Radu pretty much summed it up though.

Comment: @RaduMurzea  cancel my reopen request.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what a wheel of straight means, but not having a full straight of 5 cards in a row even 4 cards is worth nothing besides  high Card. Your value was High Card A (which is on board already)

A straight means 5 Cards in a row, so you missed a 8 or a K.

He wins with  pair of AA , that's correct.

A wheel or is  the name for the low straight  ( A-2-3-4-5 )

A steel wheel is the name for the lowest straight flush (A-2-3-4-5)

Comment: A wheel is a 5 high straight. A steel wheel is a 5 high straight flush.

Comment: thank you, I missunderstood that before. now its updated.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have a straight at all. You need 5 cards in a row for a straight and you had 9,10,J,Q. Without an 8 or a K to finish it you had nothing of worth.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that your opponent has A,A,Q,9,4
But you only have A,Q,J,10,9

You missed the straight by one card. If you got K instead of 9, it will be a straight and you might won